# Delphi code for sanitizing a URL entered by the user

Tags: delphi, url

I need a user to be able to enter a URL, and would like to make sure it is as wholesome as possible. Things like checking that there is http:// at the front, no double-dots, perhaps valid TLD, trailing slash (I have to add the final page).

I figure this is such a common requirement that it must exist already. Suggestions?

[edit:] To be clear, this is a run-time requirement in a Windows Service. The aim is to get the best from the URL read from the configuration, rather than validate what the user typed in. In essence, if I can adjust the URL and make it work, then that is what I'd like to do. The download will be a specific file, so if it all goes wrong it won't get the wrong thing from another server by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at "[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)"?  It is not Delphi specific, but might get you started.

Comment: Hmm, an interesting idea, thanks, but I'd rather "auto-correct" the URL instead of just validating it. But validating it on entry might be good to do too.

Comment: Instead of auto-correcting, you can simply show a visual sign that the entered URL is not correct.  e.g. disable the OK button or set the edit background to red.

Comment: But before you can autocorrect, you need to know what to correct, so you need some kind of validation. A nice regex will tell you if the protocol is missing, or if it ends with a slash. Use capturegroups - if they're empty - you need to add what's missing.

Answer (score 4):

How about using the [PathIsURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773724.aspx) function in the Windows API?

Update:
This is already wrapped in the Delphi RTL in the ShLwApi unit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124170/a-delphi-freepascal-lib-or-function-that-emulates-the-phps-function-parseurl) might help.

Comment: This may be a good option - break the URL into bits that exist, and then reconstitute with any missing parts.