# How can I separate the server name from the port number in a string?

Tags: string, delphi, email

If there is a mail server string like *smtp.gmail.com:587*, how could I parse it to save "smtp.gmail.com" in a string variable and "587" in another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function SplitAtChar(const Str: string; const Chr: char;
  out Part1, Part2: string): boolean;
var
  ChrPos: integer;
begin
  result := true;
  ChrPos := Pos(Chr, Str);
  if ChrPos = 0 then
    Exit(false);
  Part1 := Copy(Str, 1, ChrPos - 1);
  Part2 := Copy(Str, ChrPos + 1, MaxInt);
end;
```

Sample usage:

```
var
  p1, p2: string;
begin
  if SplitAtChar('smtp.gmail.com:587', ':', p1, p2) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(p1);
    ShowMessage(p2);
  end;
```

Comment: No need for MaxInt kludge; Just Part2 := Copy(Str, ChrPos + 1);

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Delphi XE and want a one-liner instead of bothering with regex:

```
uses
  Types, StrUtils;
var
  StrArr: TStringDynArray;
begin
  StrArr := SplitString('smtp.gmail.com:587', ':');
  Assert(StrArr[0] = 'smtp.gmail.com');
  Assert(StrArr[1] = '587');
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Delphi XE, you might also use the built-in regular expression support:

```
uses RegularExpressions;

procedure parse(const pInput: string; var vHostname,
  vPortNumber: string);
var
  l_Regex: TRegEx;
  l_Match: TMatch;
begin
  l_Regex := TRegEx.Create('^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)(:([0-9]+))?$');
  l_Match := l_RegEx.Match(pInput);
  if l_Match.Success then
  begin
    vHostname := l_Match.Groups[1].Value;
    if l_Match.Groups.Count > 3 then
      vPortNumber := l_Match.Groups[3].Value
    else
      vPortNumber := '25'; // default SMTP port
  end
  else
    begin
    vHostname := '';
    vPortNumber := '';
  end;
end;
```

This will match smtp.gmail.com:587, as well as smtp.gmail.com (in the latter case, vPortNumber is assigned the standard SMTP port 25).

Comment: If you are using earlier versions of Delphi, you could use the freely available TRegExpr - google it.

Answer (score 1):

The Indy TIdURI class can split any URI into its parts (protocol, host, port, user, password, path, etc). Indy is included in Delphi. TIdURI bas some bugs reported [here](http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/15328) and mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124170/a-delphi-freepascal-lib-or-function-that-emulates-the-phps-function-parse-url/502011#502011), planned to be fixed in Indy 11.